# Magento2 display sibling categories in layered navigation

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

In Magento2 I would like to add sibling categories to layered navigation. For example If I have a category called 'Clothes' and sub categories named 'Men' 'Women' and 'kids' respectively, Then when a customer is on the category page(where product grid is displayed with layered navigation) of 'Men' then in the layered navigation 'Shopping Options'->'Category'->'Men','Women','Kids' must be displayed with 'Men' option highlighted.

Answer (score -2):

you can use **Category List Widget** FREE Extension and than place widget any where you want from **Admin >> CMS >> Widget** Section

REF : https://store.emizentech.com/magento2/category-list-widget.html